# How do I install sketchup on ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: wine

Trying to install sketchup 2016 on ubuntu 15.10 through wine,
doesn't work.

Comment: We can only help if you tell us why it does not work. By the way: http://hrvooje.blogspot.nl/2015/11/how-to-install-sketchup-2016-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 4):

See the post: [Install Google Sketchup on Ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-google-sketchup-ubuntu1404/)

From this I understood that you need to:

type on the terminal:

`winecfg`

In **Wine Configuration** window:

1.Change Windows Version to **Windows 7** in the bottom of the Applications tab.

2.Under **Libraries** tab, select ‘Riched20’ library from the drop-down list and add it
[image: Wine configuration]

This should work for 2016 too.

Comment: Link only answers are not accepted on askubuntu. And he is asking about the 2016 version on 15.10. Knowing WINE ... it is a big deal and the WINE version will be crucial for it to work.

Comment: If Sketchup won't start and/or complains about `mfc100u.dll`, follow the instructions here: http://jesselongacre.com/blog/2015/oct/installing-sketchup-2015-64-bit-ubuntu-1404-using-wine-17#comment-66444

In short, do this: `WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.WineSketchUp/ winetricks --force vcrun2010`